# Webapplication server attack

Tags: windows-server-2008

I checked the log of my  web application (Tomcat )  and i am getting some strange requests. It looks like someone is trying some random pages to access on my application .

My question is how to stop such activities as i am having my log full of these attempts.

*122.0.76.146 - - [08/Nov/2015:00:24:45 +0000] "POST /register.do HTTP/1.1" 404 973
185.25.148.240 - - [08/Nov/2015:00:27:56 +0000] "GET /testproxy.php HTTP/1.1" 404 404
122.0.76.146 - - [08/Nov/2015:01:03:48 +0000] "POST /Main.action HTTP/1.1" 404 973
61.186.245.211 - - [08/Nov/2015:02:26:41 +0000] "GET /web-console/ServerInfo.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
61.186.245.211 - - [08/Nov/2015:02:29:48 +0000] "GET /jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=inspectMBean&name=jboss.system:type=ServerInfo HTTP/1.1" 404 997
113.204.53.134 - - [08/Nov/2015:02:32:44 +0000] "GET /invoker/JMXInvokerServlet HTTP/1.1" 404 1001
185.25.148.240 - - [08/Nov/2015:10:07:51 +0000] "GET /testproxy.php HTTP/1.1" 404 404
62.210.88.201 - - [08/Nov/2015:14:40:30 +0000] "GET /httptest.php HTTP/1.1" 404 402*

Comment: add a rule to refuse trafic without user agent

Comment: Is it causing a problem or just annoying you?  If it's not causing a problem don't worry about it.

Comment: The whole story is that . First i got login attempts on the DB port 1433   , i fixed it. I got login attempts on RDP and i fixed it  . Now i am getting on http an i can not restrict the traffic . If it is a bot which loops each 1 min on http trying random pages my app server will have to respond by 404 and that will kill the bandwidth  in my opinion .

Comment: sorry i don't have tomcat so i can't describe but tomcat doc can, just search on google `block empty user agent trafic tomcat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serving a 404 is a log entry and a neglible amount of bandwidth/resources on your web server.

You can start banning IPs but it will not stop.  If you do, you may want to configure a short expiry for it, as you may end up blocking legitimate users when those IP addresses get reassigned.

The source IPs will constantly change as there are thousands of bots/trojans which will continue to scan your web server to find a way in.

Comment: is that a real solution ? redirecting trafic before 404 wouldn't save hdd access to see if page exist ?